# How Can I define global CONST variables in Symfony framework?

Tags: php, symfony

How Can I define global CONST variables in my app symfony  ? What are the good practices define global variables in symfony?
Mayby Should I create interface and use DI ?

Comment: Depending on your need, you may be able to put them under parameters in your config.yml. Can you provide a more specific example of how you would use these vars?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add your variables into `app/config/config.yml`;

```
# app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    myVariable: 10
```

And you can use it;

```
$this->getParameter('myVariable');
```

Comment: Parameters are not constants, they are variables, hence they can have variable content, not constant.

Comment: @PaulAllsopp That's right. Actually, PHP 8 provides "Enums" for a better solution. Constant variables aren't recommended for modern applications. However, it's a trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a constant, it wont change, in other words: it's not a parameter. Therefore, has no sense and it's not optimal to put it in Symfony configuration files.

In my opinion, the best practice is to define it in the class you are using:

```
namespace App\Entity;

class Foo {
    const MyConst = 'A value';

    /* ...... */
```

If you need it in different places, you can create a class to define there your application constants:

```
namespace App\Classes;

class Constants {
    const MyConst = 'Hello world!';

     /* ...... */

}
```

Then, you can use this class wherever you need it:

```
namespace App\Controller\Frontend;

use App\Classes\Constants;

class FooController extends AbstractController
{
     /* ...... */

     public function bar()
     {
            echo Constants::MyConst;
      }

}
```

All of this is based on the fact that its value does not depend on the environment, if is not the case, you should use .env file.